# Iterating over object to see if identical values are found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to make the statement below to search the objects and see if they contain identical values.

```
$.each( winning, function( idx, obj ) {

});
```

My object looks like this:

```
var winning = [{1:0, 2:0, 3:0},{4:0, 5:0, 6:0},{7:0, 8:0, 9:0},
                     {1:0, 4:0, 7:0},{2:0, 5:0, 8:0},{3:0, 6:0, 9:0},
                     {1:0, 5:0, 9:0},{7:0, 5:0, 3:0}];
```

So lets say I am looking to see if an object inside the array of objects has a 1 for all of its values. So `{1:1, 2:1, 3:1}` would return true but `{1:1, 2:0, 3:1}` would return false.  Is this possible? The only way I can see it being done is by creating a ton of loops for each individual object. I am not very familiar with jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: Is it always groups of 3? Just sum the values of each group and see if it `== 3`.

Comment: yes it will be by default it will have 0 but it can be either -1 or 1 depending on the answers provided. How would I iterate over all the objects and sum them easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var winning = [{1:0, 2:0, 3:0},{4:0, 5:0, 6:0},{7:0, 8:0, 9:0},
                     {1:0, 4:0, 7:0},{2:0, 5:0, 8:0},{3:0, 6:0, 9:0},
                     {1:0, 5:0, 9:0},{7:0, 5:0, 3:0},{7:1, 5:1, 3:1},{7:-1, 5:-1, 3:-1},{7:-1, 5:-1, 3:0},{7:2, 5:2, 3:2}];
var len = winning.length;
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    var data = winning[i];
    var txt = "";
    var val = [];
    var flg = 1;
    $.each(data,function(k,v){
        val.push(v);
        txt += k+":"+v+" ";
    });
    var vlen = val.length;
    for(var j=0;j<vlen;j++){
        for(var k=j+1;j<vlen;j++){
            if(val[j] != val[k]){
                flg = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flg == 0){        
        txt += " false";
    }
    else{
        if(val[0] == 0){
            txt += " false";
        }
        else if(val[0] == 1){
            txt += " true 1";
        }
        else if(val[0] == -1){
            txt += " true -1";
        }
        else if(val[0] == 2){
            txt += " true 2";
        }
    }
    $("body").append("<div>"+txt+"</div>");
}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/t5NYU/2)

Comment: I have been modifying this code trying to understand how its working for over an hour and I am still having trouble with it. I would like to add another flag option since I can insert either 1 or -1 into the objects. I would like to see if an object contains -1. So `{1:-1, 2:-1, 3:-1}` would also return true but with another message. I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Comment: @Yamaha32088 I have edited answer. you can add as many options as you want to. basic logic is that all 3 numbers have to be same. is it clear now??

Answer (score 1):

You can do using [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)...

```
function checkForOne()
{
$(winning).each(function(i) {              
 for (var i in this) {
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(i)){
            if(this[i]==1)
            {
                alert("contains 1"); return false;
            }
        }
    }
});
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your example...

```
$.each( winning, function( idx, obj ) {
    var groupSum = obj.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array){
        return previousValue + currentValue;
    });
    if (groupSum == 3 || groupSum == -3) alert('Identicals');
});
```

Comment: Oh, right... it would need to be converted into an array first.